# Transfer file in blocks

Tags: c, unix, sockets

In C (UNIX), how can I transfer and receive a file in multiple blocks using a socket?

For example, if I had a file of **1234** bytes, and a block size of 500, I would transfer:

- 500 bytes,
- then 500 bytes,
- then 234 bytes

I have attempted this using fseek, read, write, but I just cannot get the logic right. Even a good reference would be much appreciated.

My socket routines are:

```
int readn(sd, chunk, bytesToRead);

int writen(sd, chunk, bytesToWrite);
```

Comment: whats not working right ?  Check those functions individually commenting all further part .....  just check it echoing(cout) the read file to console

Comment: You may have misunderstood how sockets work. If you're using a connected (TCP) socket, then the data is conceptually a stream. The actual calls to read and write do a chunk of data at a time, but they don't have to correspond. The reader and writer can each use whatever sizes they like, just be sure to check return values. It's only with UDP (connectionless) sockets that reader and writer have to manipulate the same chunks, and you rarely need UDP except for certain high-performance situations.

Comment: So for instance, suppose the writer writes 500 bytes, then 500, then 234, successfully. Then the reader can potentially read up to all 1234 bytes in a single read call, as long as it supplies a big enough buffer. Similarly, if the writer writes 1234 bytes in one go, then there's nothing wrong with the reader reading in blocks of 500, or 128, or any other size. The network chops your stream up into packets under the covers, but you can ignore that unless you are using UDP. And when writing to or reading from a socket, you almost certainly shouldn't ever be using seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using TCP then all you need to do is send your data block (I assume you have some kind of protocol which tells you how many bytes are in the block, such as a header?) and when you get your block at the other end simply write it to the file that you are writing to. TCP will deal with making sure everything is arriving in the expected order so you should just be able to walk your way through the file reading in X bytes at a time and sending them and then on the recv side you simply recv your data and write it to the file... Just remember that every read you issue on your socket can return anywhere between 1 and "block size" bytes and that your protocol should be able to tell you how many to expect and that you should then loop until you have actually got as many bytes as you'd expect...

If you're using UDP then things get a little more fun as you need to track which block a particular datagram represents...

Homework question?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that write of N bytes does not necessarily cause the read of N bytes on the receiving end. And maybe worth noting as well, that with TCP two writes of N bytes each do not necessarily cause two reads of N bytes, if the maximum size for the receive buffer is bigger than N.

Comment: Andrew, Indeed, but I was expecting that the protocol around the blocks (just a header which tells us the size?) would mean that reads were likely to be of a max "expectedBlockSize - bytesWeAlreadyHaveForThisBlock"... But it's worth you mentioning the writeSize != readSize thing explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Of the top of my head (not compiled, so see it as pseudocode):

```
bytesRemaining = 1234;
chunkSize = 500;
offset = 0;
bytesWritten = 0;

while(bytesRemaining > 0)
  {
    if(bytesRemaining < chunkSize)
      bytesToWrite = bytesRemaining;
    else
      bytesToWrite = chunkSize;

    writen(sd, chunk+offset, bytesToWrite);
    offset += bytesToWrite;
    bytesRemaining -= bytesToWrite;
  }
```

or if writen() return the number of bytes written:

```
bytesRemaining = 1234;
chunkSize = 500;
offset = 0;
bytesWritten = 0;

while(bytesRemaining > 0)
  {
    if(bytesRemaining < chunkSize)
      bytesToWrite = bytesRemaining;
    else
      bytesToWrite = chunkSize;

    bytesWritten = writen(sd, chunk+offset, bytesToWrite);
    offset += bytesWritten;
    bytesRemaining -= bytesWritten;
  }
```

The same logic can be applied to the readn() case.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. The main thing to get right is to make sure that you're IO calls actually do what you tell them to... That means checking their return codes to make sure they wrote or read the amount you expected... Also, it looks like you've wrapped read and write... Perhaps you should start by making sure they are totally correct...

Answer (score 0):

The read will only get as many bytes as are actually buffered at that time or the maximum toy specify.  So if you read frequently you will get far smaller chunks.  If this matters (and I cannot see why it should),  you need to collate the data in a secondary buffer of your own until you have the number you expect.

Of course there are perfectly good file transfer protocols such as FTP that you could use instead.